Toric domains are invariant under $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ action
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2_{>0}$ be a subset of the plane with strictly positive coordinates. We can define its associated toric domain as $X_{\Omega}=\{(z_1,z_2)\in \mathbb{C}^2:(|z_1|^2,|z_2|^2)\in\Omega\}$. I want to prove that for any $A\in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ the toric domains $X_{\Omega}$ and $X_{A\Omega}$ are symplectomorphic.
Heres what i did:
Set $A=\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c& d\end{bmatrix}$ so that $ad-bc=1$, and consider the lifting of $A$ to $\mathbb{C}^2(\approx\mathbb{R}^4$ with coordinates $(\rho_1,\rho_2,\theta_1,\theta_2)$ and the standard symplectic form $\omega=d\rho_1\wedge d\theta_1+d\rho_2\wedge d\theta_2$):
$\Phi_A(\rho_1,\rho_2,\theta_1,\theta_2)=(A\begin{bmatrix}\rho_1\\\rho_2\end{bmatrix},A^{-T}\begin{bmatrix}\theta_1\\\theta_2\end{bmatrix})$.
I can see that $\Phi_A$ preserves $\omega$, but im having trouble checking that $\Phi_A(X_\Omega)=X_{A\Omega}$...
Any help would be appreciated.

Define the coordinates $R_j = |z_j|^2$ and $\theta_j = \arctan(y_j / x_j)$ , where $z_j = x_j + i y_j$. Hence, the moment map is given by $$\mu (R_1, R_2, \theta_1, \theta_2) =  (R_1,R_2)$$ Now, according to your calculation the lifting of $A$ to $\mathbb{C}^2$ acts by: $$(R_1, R_2, \theta_1, \theta_2) \mapsto (A\begin{bmatrix}R_1\\R_2\end{bmatrix},A^{-T}\begin{bmatrix}\theta_1\ \theta_2\end{bmatrix})$$ And it should be seen from here that $\mu(\Phi_A (X_\Omega)) = A\Omega$.
